# Module Not Found Error While Using React Icons

Tags: reactjs

I am going through Lynda's Learning React course. In the first video of the 4th chapter I am facing an issue. When I type npm start on Git Bash, the following error is being displayed:

```
> bulletin-board@0.1.0 start C:\Users\John\Desktop\Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs\Files\Ch04\04_01\start\bulletin-board
> react-scripts start

The `setup` option is deprecated and will be removed in v3. Please update your config to use `before`
Starting the development server...

Failed to compile.

./src/Note.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/lib/fa/pencil' in 'C:\Users\John\Desktop\Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs\Files\Ch04\04_01\start\bulletin-board\src'
```

I have tried using number of solutions shown in Stack Overflow question related to my one. But they don't work for me.

I am stuck and can't proceed further to the course without fixing it.

Comment: `npm install` ?

Comment: It doesn't work.